# Angular: Storing Values from TinyMCE Editor

Tags: html, angular, tinymce

Is there a way to do this? I am not using the usual

```
<textarea>
```

way, but instead the editor is being called from

```
<app-tinymce-editor>.
```

I want to save the text in the editor to a variable so it can be displayed in a specific format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of tinymce-angular](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular#ngmodel) suggests either using a two way binding via ngModel

```
<editor [(ngModel)]="dataModel"></editor>
```

or an onChange handler event binding

```
<editor (onSelectionChange)="handleEvent($eventObj)"></editor>
```

Comment: Am getting undefined.

Comment: yup, also getting undefined

Answer (score 0):

The best way of getting values from editor is to use reactive form.

```
<editor formControlName="editor"
<editor>
```

you can acess it then in the component:

```
this.form.controls.editor.value
```